# How to process live sound output in Android

Tags: android, audio

I'm new to android and new to anything related to sound processing.

The thing is, I have a simple deep learning model to eliminate noise (barking dogs, cars,...). I want to apply (use) it to the sound output on android phone (ex: when I call messenger, the sound comes from my friend have barking, I will turn on my app to get rid of dog barking, I will turn on my app to eliminates dog barking) but I don't know how to do it. I have found an architecture on Windows that shows where my model is located:
[image]

On picture display shows both incoming and outgoing sound for a conversation, It adopts the driver and IOCTL protocol to interfere with the transfer of sound from user mode to the kernel and vice versa, is it the same in android? . Can someone tell me how it looks in android or any information, I've seen something [here](https://source.android.com/devices/audio) but for a novice like me it's too little information. Thank everybody!